# How to disable ckeditor from editable div?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-4, ckeditor

I'm using ckeditor in my textareas. But I don't want it to be enabled in my content editable div areas. I used ckeditor gem in my rails app.

How can I prevent ckeditor to be loaded in editable div areas?

Answer (score 6):

Disable auto

```
CKEDITOR.disableAutoInline = true;
```

and init them yourself